# Getting error with the JUnit test case . "No test found with test runner ' JUnit '

Tags: angular, junit

Getting error with the JUnit test case. "No test found with test runner ' JUnit '.
In pom its looking for dependency and mvn install fails . So how to add the dependency .in package.json jasmine is not picked during run

---

```
it('should open justification comment window, () => {
        component.onClickPassActionButton();
        expect(component.inputJustificationPopUpRef.isOpen).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should fire validation error for the textbox of justification comment window, () => {
        let action: LASUXModalAction = {};
        component.comment = "";
        component.onModalInputJustificationAction(action);
        expect(component.displayErrorForJustification).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should close justification comment window, () => {
        let action: LASUXModalAction = {};
        component.comment = "";
        component.onModalInputJustificationAction(action);
        expect(component.displayErrorForJustification).toBeFalsy();
        expect(component.comment.length<=0).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should open justification confirmation window, () => {
        let action: LASUXModalAction = {};
        component.comment = "test dummy";
        component.onModalInputJustificationAction(action);
        expect(component.displayErrorForJustification).toBeFalsy();
        expect(component.comment.length<=0).toBeFalsy();
        expect(component.confirmJustificationPopUpRef.isOpen).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should submit comment of justification comment window', inject(
        [DecisionPipelineService],
        (service: DecisionPipelineService) => {
            spyOn(service,
                'submitJustificationApproval').and.returnValue(throwError(new Error('error')));
                let action: LASUXModalAction = {};
                component.comment = "test dummy";
                component.onModalConfirmJustificationAction(action);
                expect(component.internalRequestDetails.status.toLowerCase()).toEqual("approved");
                expect(component.internalRequestDetails.fontColor).toEqual(hexColor.GREEN);
        }
    ));

    it('should close justification confirmation window & open justification comment window, () => {
        let action: LASUXModalAction = {};
        component.comment = "test dummy";
        component.onModalConfirmJustificationAction(action);
        expect(component.confirmJustificationPopUpRef.isOpen).toBeFalsy();
        expect(component.inputJustificationPopUpRef.isOpen).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the spring boot starter test in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This scope test is used to indicate that dependency isn't required at standard runtime of the application, but is used only for test purposes.

Spring boot starter test includes the following dependecies:

1. JUnit 4: The de-facto standard for unit testing Java applications.
2. Spring Test & Spring Boot Test: Utilities and integration test
   support for Spring Boot applications.
3. AssertJ: A fluent assertion library.
4. Hamcrest: A library of matcher objects (also known as
   constraints or predicates).
5. Mockito: A Java mocking framework.
6. JSONassert: An assertion library for JSON. JsonPath: XPath for JSON

The pom with adding the spring boot starter.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```